# Separability of a function, preservation only under linear transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, utility

i have a doubt about the following problem:

Lets define a multivariable function $u(x):\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which has the "additive separability" property, meaning we can writte $\displaystyle u(x) = \sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x_{l})$
We need to show that a monotonic transformation preserves this property ONLY if this transformation is affine.

The first step is to show that a affine function preserves this so called "additive separability" property:

Lets create the function $\hat{u}(x) = au(x) + b$, where $a>0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then:

\begin{align}
\hat{u}(x) = a \sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x_{l}) + b \\
\hat{u}(x) = \sum_{l=1}^{n} a u_{l}(x_{l}) + b \\
\hat{u}(x) = \sum_{l=1}^{n}( a u_{l}(x_{l}) + \frac{b}{n}) \\
\hat{u}(x) = \sum_{l=1}^{n} \tilde{u}_{l}(x_{l}) 
\end{align}

Now, my problem is to understand the second part of the proof:

We need to show that if some monotonic transformation preserves the property, it is necesarily a affine transformation:
The proof that i found states:
Lets create a monotonic transformation $u^{*}(x)=f(u(x))$
We want to show that if $u^{*}(x)=f(u(x)) = f(u(x)) = f(\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x_{l})) = \sum_{l=1}^{n}f_{l}(x_{l})$ then $f()$ is a affine function.

First:

$\dfrac{\partial u^{*}(x)}{\partial x_{j}} = \dfrac{\partial f(\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x_{l}))}{\partial x_{j}} = f'(\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x_{l}))u_{j}'(x_{j}) \hspace{2cm} (1)$

Also, since we know that $u^{*}(x)=\sum_{l=1}^{n}f_{l}(x_{l})$, then:

$\dfrac{\partial u^{*}(x)}{\partial x_{j}} = \dfrac{\partial \sum_{l=1}^{n}f_{l}(x_{l}) }{\partial x_{j}} = f_{j}'(x_{j}) \hspace{2cm} (2)$

From (1) and (2):

$f'(\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x_{l})) = \dfrac{f_{j}'(x_{j})}{u_{j}'(x_{j})} \hspace{2cm} (3)$

So, to show that $f()$ is affine is enough to show that $f'()$ is constant.

Lets use the following to vectors: $x^{1}$ and $x^{2}$, both in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that:

$\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x^{1}_{l}) \neq \sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x^{2}_{l})$ and $x^{1}_{j} = x^{2}_{j} = x_{j}$

So, because of (3):

\begin{align}
f'(\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x^{1}_{l})) = \dfrac{f_{j}'(x^{1}_{j})}{u_{j}'(x^{1}_{j})} = \dfrac{f_{j}'(x_{j})}{u_{j}'(x_{j})} \\
f'(\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x^{2}_{l})) = \dfrac{f_{j}'(x^{2}_{j})}{u_{j}'(x^{2}_{j})} = \dfrac{f_{j}'(x_{j})}{u_{j}'(x_{j})}
\end{align}

So, finally:

$f'(\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x^{1}_{l})) =f'(\sum_{l=1}^{n}u_{l}(x^{2}_{l})) $

$\square$

I understand everything except why we can state without lost of generality that the j-dimension of $x^{1}$ and $x^{2}$ are equal? Is there any other way to prove this without this assumption? It seems a strong assumption.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any other conditions on $u$? Because if $u$ is constant any $f$ preserves additive separability.